# How to apply Datatables plugin to a rendered django-tables2?

Tags: datatables-1.10, django-tables2

Problem implementing of Datatables plugin to a 'Django-tables2' rendered table.

I'm beginner at Django; I'm working on an app that shows data upload to the database (postgresql), looking for solution to the high time to render the table with many data through a normal django CVB, I found django-tables2.
I have been able to implement it and show the render table (with an important improvement on load speed), additionally, for all my tables I have implemented 'Datatables' plugin and some agregates, but I have not unscrambled how to make them work with the table rendered with django-tables2 as those do with all my other data tables (not rendered by django-tables2); until the moment the only part that partially works is the CSS, but the responsive and colReorder doesn´t work.

I have tried to specify 'static' files routes directly in the template as official documentation explains but it does not work.

The HTML template I'm using inherit form a 'base' template that implements all the css/js static files and overwrites a content block where is the place the data table is rendered.

As reference my code is:

```
Views.py

class Data_t_zq70(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = datos
        attrs = {
            'class': 'table table-sm text-center table-striped table-
bordered table-hover id=dataTable'}
        fields = ['Insp_Lot', 'Description', 'Date', 'Material',
        'Batch', 'Mean_Valuation', 'Mean', 'Lower_Limit', 'Target',
        'Upper_Limit', 'Delvry_Quantity']
per_page = 10

class zq_70(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    model = datos
    table_class = Data_t_zq70
    template_name = 'data_list_zq70.html'
    login_url = 'base:login'

HTML Template:

{% extends 'base/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load django_tables2 %}
{% block contenido %}
<div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a href="{% url 'data:data_upload' %}" class="btn btn-
               info"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"> <strong>
                              Cargar datos</strong></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
                    {% render_table table %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock contenido %}
```

Despite the datatable is rendered some elements from 'datatables' plugin are not showed like 'search' box, 'show xx entries' box, etc.

[Other tables rendered with Datatables plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XWZg.png)

[Table rendered with Django-tables2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGoTs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

datatables requires different html elements to be present compared to the table templates django-tables2 provides. I think implementing a custom template derive off of one of [the supplied templates](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/tree/master/django_tables2/templates/django_tables2) adding the elements required for datatables is the way to go.

django-tables2 might not be the best solution to render datatables-tables though, did you look into [django-datatables-view](https://pypi.org/project/django-datatables-view/)?

Answer (score 0):

I know [django-datatables-view](https://django-datatable-view.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/index.html) can directly be used to render table but if you really want to use the features of [datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) using the plugins on top of [django-table2](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), this is how you can write the `attrs` in `table.py`.

```
from django_tables2 import tables
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelTable(tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

        # This is a hack for using datatable at the frontend
        attrs = {
            'id' : 'example',  #Rename the value to match with datatable id
            'class': 'display', #Change this class value according to the documentation
            'style': 'width:100%'
            }
```

And include the databale specific css/js to your html template.

Again, this is definitely not an ideal way to use datatable in django but have fun!